# yfinance: How to access the x-values : times

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I have this code :

```
data = yf.Ticker("SHOP.TO").history(period="20d", interval="1d")
```

data contains :

```
                                 Open        High         Low       Close    Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits
Date                                                                                                        
2023-11-23 00:00:00-05:00   97.440002   97.970001   96.699997   96.699997    397100        0.0           0.0
2023-11-24 00:00:00-05:00   96.110001   96.889999   95.610001   96.260002   2160900        0.0           0.0
2023-11-27 00:00:00-05:00   98.099998  101.449997   97.000000  100.510002   3976200        0.0           0.0
2023-11-28 00:00:00-05:00   98.500000  100.800003   98.199997   99.830002   2922000        0.0           0.0
2023-11-29 00:00:00-05:00  100.989998  101.910004   99.260002   99.720001   3018500        0.0           0.0
2023-11-30 00:00:00-05:00   99.839996  100.379997   97.870003   98.849998   3741000        0.0           0.0
2023-12-01 00:00:00-05:00   98.000000   99.849998   96.989998   99.720001   2751600        0.0           0.0
2023-12-04 00:00:00-05:00   98.800003   99.699997   96.680000   98.199997   3287800        0.0           0.0
2023-12-05 00:00:00-05:00   97.500000  102.500000   96.639999  101.580002   4168000        0.0           0.0
2023-12-06 00:00:00-05:00  100.110001  100.599998   96.589996   96.709999   4511000        0.0           0.0
2023-12-07 00:00:00-05:00   96.389999   98.320000   95.040001   97.790001   2969300        0.0           0.0
2023-12-08 00:00:00-05:00   96.980003   99.195000   96.870003   98.589996   1892600        0.0           0.0
2023-12-11 00:00:00-05:00   98.190002   99.900002   97.900002   98.879997   2027600        0.0           0.0
2023-12-12 00:00:00-05:00   97.910004   98.699997   96.750000   98.540001   2836400        0.0           0.0
2023-12-13 00:00:00-05:00   98.349998  100.000000   96.669998   99.730003   3848800        0.0           0.0
2023-12-14 00:00:00-05:00  101.000000  104.080002  100.559998  103.919998   3595800        0.0           0.0
2023-12-15 00:00:00-05:00  104.000000  104.339996  102.250000  103.029999  14037100        0.0           0.0
2023-12-18 00:00:00-05:00  101.000000  103.639999  101.000000  103.300003   4404200        0.0           0.0
2023-12-19 00:00:00-05:00  103.129997  106.680000  103.099998  104.500000   4287600        0.0           0.0
2023-12-20 00:00:00-05:00  104.050003  104.919998  100.360001  100.790001   4850901        0.0           0.0
```

I know how to acces the columns such as Open and High but how would I access the Date column?